# how snakemake can transfer data between nas file system and nodes of cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, transfer, snakemake

We are developing a snake pipeline and we need to transfer data between nas file system and nodes of our cluster.
our cluster has an architecture with a /scratch directory in each node. We need copy data from nas to node /scratch before launching a rule.
Here a example of a typical slurm script we use :

```
#!/bin/bash
############      SLURM CONFIGURATION      ###################
#SBATCH --partition=supermem
#SBATCH --job-name=Spades
#SBATCH --output=Spades-out
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=8
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=20G
#SBATCH --time=100:00:00
############################################################

path_to_dir="/data3/illumina-decontamination";
path_to_tmp="/scratch/user$SLURM_JOB_ID"; 
path_to_dest="/data3/projects/Spades";

module load bioinfo/SPAdes/3.11.1

###### create repertory on scratch
mkdir $path_to_tmp;

####### copy data from nas to /scratch node
scp -r nas3:$path_to_dir $path_to_tmp
echo "tranfert donnees master -> noeud"
cd $path_to_tmp/DATA/

###### Runnning
mkdir $path_to_tmp/DATA/SpadeAssembly
spades.py .... #command line

# transfer
scp -r $path_to_tmp/illumina-decontamination/Spade_*  nas3:$path_to_dest/;
echo "Transfert donnees node -> nas3";

#### remove tmp node
rm -r $path_to_tmp;
echo "Suppression des donnees sur le noeud";
```

We are testing shadow-prefix option but it's not working. 
What is the most elegant way to do it in snakemake? We would like that our pipeline works also in a cluster without /scratch.

Thanks.

Julie

Answer (score 1):

If it's just for one rule, you can basically translate your script into a shell directive.

If you need to do this for every rule, maybe you can get [shell prefix](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#i-want-to-configure-the-behavior-of-my-shell-for-all-rules-how-can-that-be-achieved-with-snakemake) to work but it seems like support for rule variables is still a [WIP](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/137).

I would probably make a bash script to perform the copy and write back operations that take the input and output destinations.  For each rule you would

```py
shell:
   '''
   my_copy.sh {input} {config[temp]}/rule/path/{wildcards.sample}
   # do work
   my_write_back.sh {config[temp]}/rule/results/{wildcards.sample} {output}
   '''
```

In another system you can either update the temp location from scratch or change the scripts to be no ops if you work in place.  I don't think shadow prefix is what you need...

Sorry it's not a straight answer, hopefully it stimulates some ideas.